# Airport Time Capsule no Passthrough for Dual Routers

Tags: network, airport, vpn, time-capsule

The goal is a secondary VPN router since Airport Time Capsule doesn’t have that built-in capability. I’m not sure if Apple Routers have a setting to click for passthrough traffic or if I’m configuring things wrong. Most question research turns up a bridge mode and that isn’t what I want. I am banging my head on a desk since my setup appears correct.

Here are my router configurations...

Router A is an Apple Airport Time Capsule (last gen before discon) with most current firmware.
Router B is an ASUS AC66U-B1 with most current ASUS firmware.

All Masks are 255.255.255.0. The Apple has IPv6 enabled, the ASUS does not.

Router A’s IP is 10.0.0.1. The DNS server is 1.1.1.1. I assign static IPs to my local devices and have DHCP reserved higher up in the list for guests.

I assigned a static IP to Router B - 10.0.0.2.

Router B’s knows it’s WAN address is the assigned static IP 10.0.0.2. It knows the DNS and Default Gateway are 10.0.0.1. I have NAT turned off.

Router B’s LAN is 10.0.1.1 - this way the third octet is different and not assigning similar IPs. DHCP is on for my needs.

I plug in B’s WAN to A’s LAN but anything attached to Router B will not connect to the internet. I can’t figure out why.

Whatever I’m missing is blindly obvious but I just can’t see it. Thanks, experts, for your ideas on this.